# What is the significance of In-Place Algorithm while designing complex applications?

Tags: algorithm, in-place

I am aware that In-Place algorithms takes constant memory of O(log n) or O(n). But in real time while designing an complex applications or systems, how one should consider this aspect and implement it as an
 architecture point of view?

It would be very helpful if someone can explain with example or point me to the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The complexity depends on what you want to do in-place. E.g. for sorting it is O(n log n). The main advantage is that you don't need additional memory i.e. O(1) space.

Comment: In-place algorithms overwrite their input with their output, which is presumably no bigger. In the normal Word RAM machine model, an in-place algorithm is generally allowed only a constant number of words. In bitwise models like Turing machines, O(log n) is the equivalent. In-placeness is seldom important in system architecture. Rather it's an implementation detail that factors into system cost. The main exception is when data are so big that computation must be in-place to manage memory and/or communication costs or fit within fixed constraints.

Comment: Thanks @Gene for the clarification.
Also I learned from the CLR that - Application architecture does not always heavily relies on algorithms or their properties but they do contribute significantly at lower level such as in core logic, protocols, design, processing, etc.

Comment: @Blastfurnace - thanks for suggestion. i am bit  novice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - As @Gene mentioned  - Also I could deduct from the CLR book that - Application architecture does not always heavily relies on algorithms or their properties but they do contribute significantly at lower level such as in core logic, protocols, design, processing, etc.